# Compare elements of one nested list with another nested list

Tags: python, list

I got two list of lists

```
l1 = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
l2 = [['a','b',4],['c','d',1],['e','f',12],['i','j',18]]
```

I would like to iterate over `l1` and check if `l1[0]` matches with *any* `l2[2]`, In this case the output should be `[1, l1[0],l2[0]]` otherwise output is `[0, l1[0], l2[0]]`. Output should be a single nested list(or list of tuples) with result for each element of `l1`. Both lists can have different sizes.

I tried solving this with for-loop like:

```
output = list()
for i in l1:
   matched = 0
   for j in l2:
       if j[2] == i[0]:
          output.append([1,i[0], j[0]])
          matched = 1
    if matched == 0:
       output.append([0,i[0]])
```

This give correct output

```
[[1, 1, 'c'], [1, 4, 'a'], [0, 7]]
```

However I am looking for a more compact solution. Is it possible to solve this with list comprehension of something similar which can reduce number of lines involved?

I tried a nested list comprehension but couldn't make it work

```
out = [[(1,i[0],k[0]) if(k[2] == i[0]) else (0,i[0],k[0]) for k in l2] for i in l1]
print(out)
[[(0, 1, 'a'), (1, 1, 'c'), (0, 1, 'e'), (0, 1, 'i')], [(1, 4, 'a'), (0, 4, 'c'), (0, 4, 'e'), (0, 4, 'i')], [(0, 7, 'a'), (0, 7, 'c'), (0, 7, 'e'), (0, 7, 'i')]]
```

Comment: Did you consider using a `dict` for finding what you search for?

Comment: You can do this in one line, but it looks really bad.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ how bad?

Comment: @Alfe sorry not sure how to use `dict` here

Comment: `[next(([1, x[0], y[0]] for y in l2 if x[0] == y[-1]), [0, x[0], l2[-1][0]]) for x in l1]`

Comment: Indeed, building a dict would be the smart thing to do.

Comment: How is the `[0, 7, 'i']` as last element correct?  Why the `'i'` in it?

Comment: @Alfe yes i just noticed this. Good catch. I have updated my question

Comment: The first list you can do something like this:  `map(lambda x: x[0],l1)` and all will be cleaner. Because you only need the first elements of each list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it seems that you're not using all your elements. However, I'd build a dict out of `l2` for quick lookup & concision (one-liner would be probably possible, but at the expense of readability & performance)

I'd make that follow with a list comprehension including a ternary to issue 2 or 3 elements depending if the item is found (so no need for a fancy `int(if a in l2d)` since we can issue 0 or 1 directly). Like this:

```
l1 = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
l2 = [['a','b',4],['c','d',1],['e','f',12],['i','j',18]]

l2d = {v[2]:v[0] for v in l2}  # not using v[1]

result = [[1,a,l2d[a]] if a in l2d else [0,a] for a,_,_ in l1]  # using only first element of each l1 triplet...
```

result:

```
[[1, 1, 'c'], [1, 4, 'a'], [0, 7]]
```

(note that carrying other unused items isn't really helping to understand the issue)

Comment: I have updated my question. In case of no match `i[0]` will be the output

Answer (score 1):

Better build a dictionary to speed up searching.

```
d = { c: a for [a,b,c] in l2 }
```

Now you can use this:

```
[[int(a in d), a] + ([d[a]] if a in d else [])
 for a,b,c in l1]
```

This returns

```
[[1, 1, 'c'], [1, 4, 'a'], [0, 7]]
```